# How come queries aren't being added to Django's db.connection.queries in tests?

Tags: python, sql, django, testing

I'm trying to capture the queries which my code submits to the database by examining the contents of `django.db.connection.queries`.  For some reason though, after all the automatically produced setup queries are logged, no further queries are logged from my own code.  The following test case demonstrates the behavior.

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.db import reset_queries, connection
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings

class Test1(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        settings.DEBUG = True

    def test1(self):
        self.assert_(settings.DEBUG, 'DEBUG is False')
        reset_queries() #clears out all the setup queries
        User.objects.all()
        self.assert_(connection.queries, 'No queries')
```

And here are the results of running it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jacob/foo/bar_project/baz_application/tests.py", line 246, in test1
    self.assert_(connection.queries)
AssertionError: No queries
```

Would anyone be able to shed some light on this?  Thanks.

Comment: I was able to make the test pass. See my answer.

Comment: For those interested in checking the **number of queries**, there's also [`assertNumQueries`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TransactionTestCase.assertNumQueries). This prints the queries if the assertion fails. If you use it as context manager, you can also `print(connection.queries)` yourself, inside the `with` block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will not see any queries after executing `User.objects.all()`. This is only to be expected. The reason? Querysets are *lazy*. Unless you do something with the queryset NO query will be triggered. To verify this hypothesis, try the following and see if the test passes.

```
class Test1(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        settings.DEBUG = True

    def test1(self):
        self.assert_(settings.DEBUG, 'DEBUG is False')
        reset_queries() #clears out all the setup queries
        print User.objects.all() # <============= Printing the queryset.
        self.assert_(connection.queries, 'No queries')
```

Answer (score 9):

You have to explicitly set `DEBUG`.  For example, see the sample usage section for [these tests](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/select_related/#sample-usage) in the django documentation:

```
# Set up.
# The test runner sets settings.DEBUG to False, but we want to gather queries
# so we'll set it to True here and reset it at the end of the test suite.
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> settings.DEBUG = True
```

UPDATE: I may be missing something, but doing it in each test should definitely fix the issue.  Take a look at the [`DjangoTestSuiteRunner`](http://code.djangoproject.com/svn/django/trunk/django/test/simple.py) -- it seems that `DEBUG` is set False in the `setup_test_environment`, which is called in `run_tests`, which goes on to instantiate a `DjangoTestRunner` and call its `run method`.  So you'll need to undo that -- based on a quick scan of the [code](http://code.djangoproject.com/svn/django/trunk/django/test/simple.py), it might be sufficient to do this in your `setup` method.

Comment: Already did that, thanks.  There are about 5000 sql statements from setting up the test db that are being cleared by the `reset_queries()` call. Any other ideas?

Comment: Oh, you mean in the test itself??

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  It didn't seem to change anything, unfortunately, per my update.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 5):

When you run tests [`DEBUG` is set to `False` explicitly](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#other-test-conditions) by Django test framework.

Comment: Thanks.  It's weird that even setting it back to True myself in the test doesn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers:

Instead of overriding `settings.DEBUG` in your `setUp()`, you can modify `DEBUG` *temporarily* by using [(Simple)TestCase.settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.settings) as a context manager, as follows:

```py
class Test1(TestCase):
    def test1(self):
        with self.settings(DEBUG=True):
            # Evaluate queryset here
            ...
        print(connection.queryset)
```